# Do not add an object to the recyclerview

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I need to populate a recycler view using a search parameter provided by a textField.

This recyclerview is made up of all the users of my app where I shouldn't be there though, since I can't search myself.

I use firestore and FirebaseUI to populate the recycler view and to populate the recycler view with each letter written in the textfield I use this method:

```
 searchParameter.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), s -> {

            Query query = Firestore.COLLECTION_REFERENCE_USER
                    .orderBy("username")
                    .startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");

            //RecyclerOptions
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserModel>()
                    .setQuery(query, UserModel.class)
                    .build();

            adapter.updateOptions(options);

        });
```

The usernames in my app do not have uniqueness but what has uniqueness is the user's email so my first solution was to add a parameter to be considered different to this query so as below:

```
 Query query = Firestore.COLLECTION_REFERENCE_ISCRITTO
                    .orderBy("username")
                    .startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff")
.whhereNotEqualTo(Firestore.KEY_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
```

This doesn't work because I sort my results by username so I thought, if I can't fix the problem in the query, I can fix it in my adapter's onbindViewHolder method.

**Question**
It exists and if so, what is a good strategy for, after verifying that the item to be inserted is an item with my email, avoid inserting this item via onBindViewHolder?

Comment: What kind of filtration you need to have in the data could you please elaborate?

Comment: Use this in onBindViewHolder ```if(uid.equals(id))
        {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams param = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams)holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            param.height = 0;
            param.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {}``` i found this few days ago here. I haven't tested it yet but seems promising.

Comment: [That's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) why that query doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, the OP confirmed that the solution was to use the following on BindViewHolder:

```
if(uid.equals(id)){
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams param = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams)holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    param.height = 0;
    param.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} 
else {}
```